# Restore recyclerview scroll position on screen orientation android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview whose data is loaded from the server. It has a `GridLayout` as its `layoutmanager`. On screen orientation I want to retain the scroll position of the `recyclerview`. I tried many some solutions from the stackoverflow. But its not working perfectly. I mean "not working perfectly" its not retaining the proper scroll position after screen orientation multiple times. Here is my code implementation:

`onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`:

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        listState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
        outState.putParcelable(Constants.POSITION, listState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        // Retrieve list state and list/item positions
        if (state != null) {
            listState = state.getParcelable(Constants.POSITION);
            Log.e(TAG, "list state not null");
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }

    private void restoreState() {
        Log.e(TAG, "restoreStated called");
        if (listState != null) {
            recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
            listState = null;
        }
    }
```

calling restore state after setting the data:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
        movieListViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieListViewModel.class);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        adapter = new MovieListAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        movieListViewModel.getMovieList();
        observePopularMovieList();

    }

private void observePopularMovieList() {
        movieListViewModel.result.observe(this, new Observer<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable NetworkResponse networkResponse) {
                if (networkResponse.getPostData() != null) {
                    movieData = networkResponse.getPostData();
                    adapter.addData(movieData.getResults());
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            restoreState();
                        }
                    },50);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failure");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Are you using two different layouts for vertical and horizontal view?

Comment: No I am not. There is a single layout.@Bek

Comment: post your `restoreState()` code

Comment: Its already been added in the post. Please check @Jayanth

Comment: save it to shared pref, easiest part

Comment: @xoxo you should make use of savedInstanceBundle rather than saving it in some variable because when screen orientation changes activity will be destroyed and recreated so all your activity states will be destroyed and created as new ones

Comment: @xoxo i have posted answer, let me know if it works!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the recycler view in a activity try saving the recyclerViewAdapter in a ViewModel of the activity and on orientation change get the adapter and set it to the recyclerview.

If you have the recyclerview in a fragment then try getting the same fragment on orientation change

`Fragment savedFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Fragment_having_recyclerview");`

then set this fragment instead of creating a new instance of the same fragment

Comment: If I declare adapter inside viewmodel. Then I am breaking the separation of concerns right ? Now ViewModel will have a reference to `android.*` package.

Comment: Nope.  It will not have the android.* package. It will have                               import com.zoho.appname.activity.fragments.RecyclerViewAdapter;

Comment: Is the reyclerview in a fragment ?

Comment: its in the `Activity`.

Comment: So on screen orientation, the activity oncreate is called again where the recyclerview and its adapter is created and initialized freshly and the data is set to it.. thats y the recyclerview scroll is not maintained.

Comment: You try not to create the adapter again on orientation change , instead save the adapter state and use it.

Comment: I tried saving the recyclerViewAdapter in a ViewModel of the activity and not initialise it again on orientation change but it doesn't keep the recycler view position.

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of savedInstanceBundle rather than saving it in some variable because when screen orientation changes activity will be destroyed and recreated so all your activity states will be destroyed and created as new ones.

```
 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      savedInstanceState.putInt("pos", mRecyclerView.getAdapterPosition()); // gives current recycle view position.
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

and then in `onCreate()` you can get the position like this.

```
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ..
        ..
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerAdapter);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
          mRecyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int pos = savedInstanceState.getInt("pos");
                mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(pos);     
            }
        });

      }  

}
```

Create `getAdapterPosition()` inside your Adapter class like this.

```
private class ComponentRecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComponentHolder> {

  ComponentHoder myHolder = null;

        @Override
        public ComponentHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.one_component_item_list, parent, false);
            return new ComponentHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ComponentHolder holder, int position) {
            ..
            ..
            ..
            this.myHolder  = holder;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
                ..
        }
        public int getAdapterPosition(){
           return myHolder =! null ? myHolder.getAdapterPosition() : 0;
        }
    }
```

let me know if it works. Happy coding :)

Comment: `mRecyclerView.getAdapterPosition()` there is no such method. I have already seen this answer in some other post.

Comment: @sagarsuri you must make that method on your own.

Answer (score 0):

After trying lot of solutions , this helped me exactly to restore recyclerview position

```
  @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            if (newConfig.orientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE || newConfig.orientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER) {            
                if(mRecyclerView!=null && mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()!=null) {
                    mBundleRecyclerViewState = new Bundle();
                    mListState = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
                    mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE, mListState);
                }

            } else if (newConfig.orientation == SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
                        if(mRecyclerView!=null && mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()!=null) {
                            mListState = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE);
                            mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(mListState);
                        }

                    }, 100);
                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: using `postDelayed()` doesn't look clean to me.

Comment: test it by removing handler or reduce the delay